# C99- Condition is always true inside function

Tags: c, function, c99

I am writing a function, that has a part that needs to only be run once. I tried creating a local flag variable, but somehow, I get an error message. that the condition is always true.
A simplified version of my function looks like this:

```
void showMainMenu(bool *bool_drawMainMenu, TTF_Font *font1, TTF_Font *font2){
        while(*bool_drawMainMenu){
        bool flag=true;
        if(flag){
            flag=false;
            renderMenu(font1,text_Surface,text_Texture,renderer,mainMenu,3);
            SDL_Rect where={720/2,150};
        }
//...
```

Comment: What is the error message? When is it issued? Who issues it?

Comment: _I get an error message_, do you mean a warning?

Comment: Please present the example to be a complete, runnable [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you mean "run once during each call of the function" or do you mean "run once only during first call of that function."?

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
void showMainMenu(bool *bool_drawMainMenu, TTF_Font *font1, TTF_Font *font2){
    bool flag=true;
    while(*bool_drawMainMenu){
    if(flag){
        flag=false;
        renderMenu(font1,text_Surface,text_Texture,renderer,mainMenu,3);
        SDL_Rect where={720/2,150};
    }
//...
```

If you re-define the flag variable in each loop, it will always be true when you get to the if.